# How to have multiple views on a screen in iOS swift app using a ViewController

Tags: swift, google-maps, view, uiview, uiviewcontroller

So I have an app that I am making in swift for iPhone which I am fairly new at. It uses a google map and what I want to do is when the user clicks the marker it shows some information on the marker in a separate box on the bottom. Top half is the google map and bottom half is the information box. I am using a view controller for the google map view and Im trying to figure out how do I get a seperate view to show up on the bottom half, but I can only get one view to be controlled at one time and nothing online is pointing me in the right direction it seems or telling me if this is even possible. Can I have a view controller show multiple views at once/How do I split my screen between multiple views using a ViewController?

For reference this is my code so far for my ViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {
            
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("My API Key)
        
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 37.0902, longitude: -95.7129, zoom: 3.2)
        
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.bounds, camera: camera)
        mapView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(mapView)
        
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.0902, longitude: -95.7129)
        marker.title = "Title"
        marker.snippet = "snippet"
        marker.map = mapView
    }
    
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        // show info from the marker in a seperate view on bottom half
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Look into a table view or a collection view, showing multiple UiViews in a UiViewController is a default, Every UiViewController has multiple UIViews

Comment: you can `embed` one view controller (e.g. google maps) into the other view controller, which can have that embedded view, plus whatever bottom portion you need. See: https://medium.com/overapp-ios/view-controller-containment-and-delegation-pattern-f01ad105822 for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to use AutoLayout constraints.

You are currently adding your GMSMapView.map with a frame that fills your view controller's entire subview, but not setting any auto layout constraints.

You should:

1. Set your map view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false`
2. Add layout anchors to set your maps leading, trailing, and top edges to the view controller's content view leading/trailing/top edges, and the bottom constraint to the content view's vertical center.
3. Add your other views as subviews of your content view, inside a rectangle that starts at the vertical center of your view, goes to the bottom of the content view, and is pinned to the leading and trailing edges

The layout will look something like this:

```
|--------------|
|              |
|   map view   |
|              |
|--------------|
|              |
| other views  |
|              |
|--------------|
```

You could also add a vertical stack view to your view controller, then add your map view and your other view to the stack view. The stack view would then manage the two child views.

Note that you might find it easier to do your layout and set up your auto layout constraints in a Storyboard, then connect IBOutlets from your storyboard into your view controller.